# Simplifying Project Folders when Upgrading from VS 2017 to VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Probably a dumb question, but I've searched the world over and can't find a clear answer...

I upgraded from VS 2017 to VS 2019. All my existing Projects/Solutions are in C:\users\xxx\documents\Visual Studio 2017. And now VS 2019 gives a separate VS 2019 folder in the same location.

Now I know I can ask VS to use either the Projects folder under 2017 or the one under 2019 to get my projects, but it would be nice if I can move all my 2017 Projects to the 2019 Projects folder so they're all in one place. And it seems to work.

Am I missing something? Is it really as easy as copying all the 2017 Projects folder contents to the 2019 folder?

Thanks.

Comment: It is that easy.  Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations to keep using those folders.

Comment: Great. Thanks much.